# Different upper margin for the second page of table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, margins

I am writing a thesis, and I need to change the upper margin for the second page for the table of contents only. The university demands 2in upper margin for first page of ToC, followed by 1.25in upper margin for next page. I need help.

MWE is here:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letter]{report}
\usepackage{univ}
\usepackage{u-local}
\usepackage{local}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\usepackage{srcltx}

\begin{document}
 \pagenumbering{gobble}

% \setlength{\headheight}{-0.01 in}
\begin{spacing}{1.45}
 \tableofcontents
\end{spacing}
\clearpage

\pagestyle{fancy}
 \lhead{}
 \chead{}
 \rhead{\thepage}
 \lfoot{}
 \cfoot{}
 \rfoot{}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.00in}
 \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.00in}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\normalsize\filcenter\bfseries}{\centering\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\normalsize\uppercase}

\input{chapters}
\clearpage
\appendixtitleon
\appendixtitletocon
\begin{appendix}
    \input{appendices}
\end{appendix}

\begin{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{utdbibliography}

\pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{vita}
        \input{vita}
    \end{vita}
\end{document}
```

In this, `chapters`, `appendices`, `bibliography` and `vita` are different files and the text is in those files. Also, `univ`, `local` and `u-local` are different .sty files for setting space and formats for different pages. For ToC page, the setting is as follows:

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\@dotsep}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\normalsize\cftdotfill{\cftchapdotsep}}
```

Comment: Document elements like the ToC are heavily depending on the class and/or packages you're using. As such, please include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/MNP7L) that clearly shows some document construction and a 2-page ToC.

Comment: Presumably the `geometry` package might be able to help out here, in particular, `\newgeometry` for the second page. Of course, as Werner says, a MWE would go a long way :) [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Also, what about the other pages of your thesis? What dimensions should they have?

Comment: @Werner MWE is here: \usepackage{fancyhdr} \usepackage{setspace} \doublespacing \usepackage[compact,tiny]{titlesec} \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} \gdef \ttl@space {0} % Table of Contents styling using tocloft. \usepackage[titles]{tocloft} \setcounter{tocdepth}{3} \renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS} \renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize} \renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalsize} \renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\@dotsep} \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\normalsize\cftdotfill{\cftchapdotsep}}
sorry for bad presentation. how can i improve it? i am new to this.

Comment: @ArunDesiraju: You should click "edit" underneath your question and add your code there. If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Also, make sure your MWE starts with `\documentclass{something}` and ends with `\end{document}` -- otherwise it's most likely not a _working_, i.e. compilable, minimal example. If you're still unsure what a MWE is, check out the page Werner linked to in his first comment. Thanks for your efforts `:)`

Comment: @doncherry : I have added the MWE. Please check it out

Comment: @cmhughes here the ToC is generated implicitly, I can't modify any content explicitly. I had tried using \newgeometry, but it won't work.

Comment: @ArunDesiraju: Thanks! A MWE, by definition, should run on _any user's_ computer; consequently, it shouldn't contain any custom packages (`univ`, `local`, `u-local`), and preferably you shouldn't use `\input` statements and the like. You want just want one solid block of code, which everybody can copy and compile on their system to see what you're trying and where the problem is. When you look at other users' questions, you'll notice how sensible such a format is.

Comment: No usable MWE (depends on local-only packages), so 'too localized' without further edits.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the margin for the other pages (different from the first one) is already set and that the problem is with the first page of the ToC; since you are using the `tocloft` package, you can simply set the appropriate value for `\cftbeforetoctitleskip` using something like:

```
\setlength\cftbeforetoctitleskip{-1cm}
```

of course, instead of `-1cm` you should use the length that produces the desired value.

Comment: Can you please mention where need to add \setlength\cftbeforetoctitleskip{-1cm}?